# PHP Collection in a session

Tags: php, oop, session

I am developing an object oriented application using PHP v5.6 (Windows Server 2012 R2). My application uses a Collection object based off the [example here](http://www.aaron-fisher.com/articles/web/php/object-collections-in-php/) that holds my LineItem objects. I build my Collection of LineItem(s) serialize it with the php [serialize() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and put it in a $_SESSION variable to use on the next page. I am then able to retrieve my Collection and LineItem(s) object on the next page.

The following is a sample of what shows in my session file:

`楬瑳獼ㄺ㔲㐷㨷伢㠺∺獅楴慭整㨢㨵獻ㄺ㨰"*扯敪瑣≳愻㐺㌷笺㩩㬰㩏㨸䰢湩䥥整≭㤺笺㩳㨵"*摩㬢㩳㨱ㄢ㬢㩳ㄱ∺⨀瀀`

I have other php applications that serialize objects with protected properties and I am able to view my session file and read the data in a readable English language format.

This is not a critical issue, I am still able to rebuild my Collection from the session variable, but I am really curious as to what is the cause of this.

LineItem Class:

```
 <?php
class LineItem
{
    protected $id;
    protected $parentID;
    protected $name;
    protected $qty;
    protected $itemType;
    protected $UOM;
    protected $cost;
    protected $price;
    protected $rate;
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getParentID(){
    return $this->parentID;
}

public function setParentID($parentID){
    $this->parentID = $parentID;
}

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name){
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getQty(){
    return $this->qty;
}

public function setQty($qty){
    $this->qty = $qty;
}

public function getItemType(){
    return $this->itemType;
}

public function setItemType($itemType){
    $this->itemType = $itemType;
}

public function getUOM(){
    return $this->UOM;
}

public function setUOM($UOM){
    $this->UOM = $UOM;
}

public function getCost(){
    return $this->cost;
}

public function setCost($cost){
    $this->cost = $cost;
}

public function getPrice(){
    return $this->price;
}

public function setPrice($price){
    $this->price = $price;
}

public function getRate(){
    return $this->rate;
}

public function setRate($rate){
    $this->rate = $rate;
}
}
```

Comment: What are those, hieroglyphs?

Comment: I have no idea.